# MsgBox YesNo solution needed

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have done the following in a LoginForm:

```
Private Sub OK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles        OK.Click
    If UsernameTextBox.Text = ("username") And PasswordTextBox.Text = ("password") Then   MainMenu.Show(Me.Hide) Else MsgBox("Wrong")
End Sub
```

But it gives me the following error:

Error   1 Expression does not produce a value (on Me.Hide)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the LoginForm is the "startup" for the application, note that other forms will become children of this form. You'll be able to close the application one with Application.Exit() which is really not a good practice. You should close the application by closing the "startup" form.

With that said, Ranhiru is correct.

```
MainMenu.Show 'Show the MainMenu form
Me.Hide 'Hide the LoginForm
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to hide the Main Menu and Hide the current form ?

If so, try

```
If UsernameTextBox.Text = ("username") And PasswordTextBox.Text = ("password") Then  
  MainMenu.Show
  Me.Hide
Else 
  MsgBox("Wrong")
```

Comment: No Im trying to hide the login form so that the MainMenu can then be the only form on the screen.